Unexpected formatting of PostgreSQL timestamptz column in function returning json
I have a function returning json that contains a timestamptz. When I execute it in Datagrip console, I get json like
{..., "time_created":"2024-05-15T11:14:23.384266+00:00",...}.

But when I execute the same function in C# with ExecuteScalar, returned value is like
{..., "time_created":"2024-05-15T09:14:23.384266+02:00",...}

It behaves the same even if the function returns json casted to text beforehand. Note that timestamps are converted to server time zone, and server time offset if added. This cannot be rendered in Quasar controls without modification.
What causes ExecuteScalar to do the conversion even if text is returned from the function?
If a function returns a table containing timestamptz, values are returned correctly, and serialization creates values in the form e.g. "time_created":"2024-05-15T11:14:23.384266Z" which can be rendered fine in Quasar input.
Is there a way to force whatever is converting json strings while reading with ExecuteScalar to do it with ...Z?
The function is
create function data_survey_r("Key" integer) returns text language plpgsql as $$ 
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t)::text FROM data.survey t WHERE t.id = "Key");
END $$;

or
create function data_survey_r("Key" integer) returns json language plpgsql as $$ 
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t) FROM data.survey t WHERE t.id = "Key");
END $$;

It is called from C# as
ret = (string) await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync("data_survey_r", new { Key = key }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

EDIT: (The text from this comment):
create function test_now () returns json as $$ 
BEGIN   
   return (SELECT json_build_object('now', now())); 
END $$ 
language plpgsql  

C#
NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_options.ConnectionString); 
con.Open(); 
var ret = await con.ExecuteScalarAsync("test_now");  

Result: {"now" : "2024-06-22T12:53:30.515689+00:00"}
in console, {"now" : "2024-06-22T14:53:40.079963+02:00"}

Show us the definition of your (PL/pgSQL?) FUNCTION.

so the time values are exactly the same, but when you use pgadmin4 you get the UTC value (+00:00) and else you get the value adjusted for your time zone (+02:00). Cant it be an automatic session setting in pgadmin4 that does SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';

Added code fragment to the question. pgAdmin was used as a "generic" name, I am actually using DataGrip console. The fact that puzzles me is that some middleware is modifying the returned text in ExecuteScalar.

@VedranMornar and you have created a simple testing "DateTime.Now" (RETURN NOW())... function that behaves in the way you want when invoked in same way for the two scenarios from your example?

pg: ```create function test_now () returns json as $$ BEGIN
return (SELECT json_build_object('now', now()));
END $$ language plpgsql
C# ```NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_options.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
var ret = await con.ExecuteScalarAsync("test_now");

Result:
{"now" : "2024-06-22T12:53:30.515689+00:00"} in console, {"now" : "2024-06-22T14:53:40.079963+02:00"} in C#

I presume your computer is localized in a UCT+2 timezone.
By default, when you do DateTime.Now.ToString()in .NET, it will format it in the current timezone. To write a date in the ISO 8601 format, you can use the "o" format key :
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o") : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip

@Bisjob postgres is doing the time-zone formatting in the json, please see my answer.

Please [edit] your question title to describe the actual problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is primarily the useless repetition of the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will be able to tell what it contains. Your title now is just useless noise.

Changed. Hope it is less useless now.

I think we managed to get to the culprit in the comments discussion by using the diagnostic test_now function (whose definition and outputs you later added to the question)
It demonstrates that postgres is responsible for generating the timespantzformatting in the json based on the time zone set for your connection/session (which presumably for Npgsql is the time zone of your computer +02:00, possibly set to +00:00 UTC for DataGrip)
This postgres logic can be quickly tested with psql:
select test_now();
                  test_now
---------------------------------------------
 {"now" : "2024-06-22T19:17:45.53308+03:00"}
(1 row)

SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SET 

select test_now();
                   test_now
----------------------------------------------
 {"now" : "2024-06-22T16:18:11.827584+00:00"}
(1 row)

ExecuteScalar() does not play a role as suggested by your question

What causes ExecuteScalar to do the conversion even if text is
returned from the function?

but confirms your initial observation:

It behaves the same even if the function returns json casted to text
beforehand.

We could do the SET TIME ZONE from within our c# code as suggested here but we will still get UTC time in format which you don't desire (...+00:00 vs ...Z) as per your original question:

Is there a way to force whatever is converting json strings while
reading with ExecuteScalar to do it with ...Z?

I am not familiar with a way for Dapper to add some interceptors when doing ExecuteScalar and modify the generated json string with a date-format of our choosing which would be the ideal solution. Similar relatively recent use case with some solutions, but also with a comment from Marc Gravell here.

Dapper wants nothing to do with your fancy serialization shenanigans
:) Basically, no: read it from the database as a string, then
deserialize.

If that's not avaialble, we have two options -

doing it in postgres or
finding a way to convert to the desired format after we get the undesired formatted json string from ExecuteScalar

Your original function
create function data_survey_r("Key" integer) returns text language plpgsql as $$ 
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t)::text FROM data.survey t WHERE t.id = "Key");
END $$;

uses ROW_TO_JSON which doesn't allow for formatting suggestions to timespantz, however in this answer there is a suggestion of how to work around this:

There is no way to influence the format used by row_to_json.
You could define a view on your table and use
to_char(row_added_dttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z"')
to format the timestamp as a string.
Then you can use row_to_json on that view to get your desired result.

also note the comment which provides alternative approach.

A very comprehensible answer, thanks a lot. I was not aware that my environment (I am using DataGrip) works as if SET TIMEZONE 'UTC'; was set, so I wrongfully blamed the middleware. In pgAdmin it works differently by default. Anyhow, this +00.00 or whatewer is not good in Javascript, so I will go with the view or with some SELECT format_date(date_field), ... function.
